# SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x

When executing with Python it shows error:

```
return (x * (1.0 — x))
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

How do I correct it?

Comment: This problem could catch many programmers off guard (especially if they are copying code, which is bad but we all do it occasionally). Unless it is a duplicate I do not think it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the correct character for you minus operator: `-`. You are using some other 'dash' character that the interpreter is considering just a name like `y` or `x`. But it is invalid!

```
>>> bad_minus = "—"
>>> good_minus = "-"
>>> bad_minus == good_minus
False
>>> ord(good_minus)
45
>>> ord(bad_minus)
8212
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue, but with a non-breakable space I added by mistake. Your `ord` idea helped me to debug :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the character between `1.0` and `x` is supposed to be a minus sign, replace it with an actual minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

Your minus is not a minus. It's a "em dash".
Try replacing this `'—'` with `'-'`.